# Intuit QuickBooks Merchant Service + php

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I try integrate my web applacation with Intuit QuickBooks Merchant Service.
I found this https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=50&threadid=11829

But I don't understand what is it $connection_ticket, where I can get it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "connection ticket" is a token you get from Intuit, which allows you charge credit cards through their API. It's sort of like a username/password, or an OAuth token if you're familiar with that.

If you read the documentation included in the example scripts, you'll find the documentation says...:

> - IMPORTANT *  In order to use this example, you'll need to go through the Intuit  application registration process first! This is documented
>     here: 
>     http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbms_integration

If you then follow that URL, you'll find instructions to get your connection ticket.

The easiest way to get a connection ticket is to use DESKTOP mode. HOSTED mode will work too, but it's much more difficult to get a connection ticket in HOSTED mode.

Here's a direct link:

- [QuickBooks Merchant Services - get your connection ticket in DESKTOP mode](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbms_integration#getting_started_with_the_desktop_communication_model)

Comment: Thanks! I have read this manual, but I cannot understand what I must to do next. Thanks one more time!

Comment: Please, could you help me with this:

Comment: Please, could you help me with this: Usually when using payment gateways I use 'Authorize' (for checking credit card with small amount, eg $1.00), 'Void' (for unlock amout after Authorize), 'Refund' (for returning money to customer) and 'Sale' (for debit amount from customer's credit card). I found type 'Charge' but as I understood it is Authorize+Capture. What type of transaction I must use for debit credit card?

Comment: An authorize($Card, $amount) authorizes an amount on a card. A void($Transaction) voids an authorization/charge. A capture($Transaction, $amount=null) captures a previous authorization. A charge($Card, $amount) actually debits the credit card. The ->charge(...) method *is* what you're looking for.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to remove a step from your process, you can also just do an authorize(...) and then a capture($Card, $amount). Then you don't need to do the void(...) at all.

Comment: Per the directions, the next thing you need to do is register your application here: http://appreg.intuit.com

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same hazzle a few years ago.  It is not an obvious issue.  A connection ticket is actually an approval from the Intuit Payment underwriting to allow your app integtration with the Payment gateway. In my particular situation, I was a merchant account holder which allowed me to accept credit card using  sent QuickBooks Online invoices and the use of a virtual terminal at the Intuit Merchant Solution website.

But to my surprise, this does not mean that you get automatic authority to develop apps to do the same thing.  In my particular scenario, I want to link my website shopping cart to Intuit Payments.  But at the end of hundreds of hours invested in this development work, I was decnied a connection ticket.

Again, this happened about 4 years ago. I am not sure if now days there are flexible about these things or have finally come to trust their own SKD or API tools issue to developers.